# Alter Data in Varchar field

Tags: sql

Was wondering if there is an easy way to add a character / number to a varchar field on bulk?  In VN they are changing the Area codes and i need to update a Phone and Fax field on a table from the existing code to the new one.

For example a phone number is loaded as 84-8-12345678 and the new number would be 84-28-12345678.

The variable will differ for location but this I can control by the code attached to the record.

Can this be done by script?  I was thinking maybe grabbing the records and altering in excel and then uploading and updating.

Any help / suggestions appreciated.

Comment: it's called an UPDATE statement....

Comment: If you don't understand @MitchWheat's comment, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.  Having said that, for the example you gave, the syntax depends on your database engine, which you didn't specify.

Comment: Would be helpful if we knew your RDBMS (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.) so we could give specific advice

Comment: Please help us to help you. Put relevant tags and include all other relevant info, like which DB engine, and what you have attempted so far. [READ THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know about the update statement and you are wondering about the string manipulation part, you could try something like...

```
declare @ph as varchar(15) = '84-8-12345678'
select STUFF(@ph,4,0,'2')
```

Read up on String functions for your database engine because there are lots of ways to achieve this.